# How to separate values ​into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this:

| ID | Role | Control Unit | User ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00196 | SPV / TL / CS | 00G (nol) | 0016506 , 0016551 , 0016541 |
| 00237 | SPV,CS, TL | 14I | 1458506, 1458541 |
| 00196 | SPV / CS / TL | 0C3 | 0435506, 0435541, 0435551 |

I want to separate the User ID based on their respective roles, so it looks like this:

| ID | Role | Control Unit | User ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00196 | SPV | 00G (nol) | 0016506 |
| 00196 | TL | 00G (nol) | 0016551 |
| 00196 | CS | 00G (nol) | 0016541 |
| 00237 | SPV | 14I | 1458506 |
| 00237 | CS | 14I | 1458541 |
| 00237 | TL | 14I | NULL |
| 00196 | SPV | 0C3 | 0435506 |
| 00196 | CS | 0C3 | 0435541 |
| 00196 | TL | 0C3 | 0435551 |

The rules of User IDs is:

- XXXX506 - XXXX510 = SPV
- XXXX541 - XXXX550 = CS
- XXXX551 - XXXX560 = TL

The first four digits of each User ID are the branch code, so you can ignore that. Just take the last three numbers for each role.

Comment: So what is your question here? What is the difficulty *you* are having achieving your goal(s)? Where did you get stuck? What is your attempt(s)? Why didn't they work?

Comment: Why does `TL` for `00237` have a value of `NULL` for `UserID` and not `0435551`?

Comment: Is the separator can be different in one column? once `/` and next record it `,` one record it contain spaces another without ?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using JSON to *tokenize* string of tokens.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl table (ID CHAR(5), ROLE VARCHAR(200), ControlUnit VARCHAR(20), UserID VARCHAR(200))
INSERT @tbl (ID, Role, ControlUnit, UserID) VALUES
('0019', 'SPV / TL / CS', '00G (nol)',  '0016506 , 0016551 , 0016541'),
('0023', 'SPV / CS / TL', '14I',        '1458506, 1458541, 0435551'),
('0019', 'SPV / CS / TL', '0C3',        '0435506, 0435541, 0435551');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS 
(
     SELECT ID, ControlUnit, Role, UserID
         , s = '["' + REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE([Role],'json'), '\/', '","') + '"]'
         , s1 = '["' + REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(UserID,'json'), ',', '","') + '"]'
     FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID, TRIM([Role].[value]) AS [Role], ControlUnit, TRIM(UserID.[value]) AS UserID
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (s, N'$') AS [Role]
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (s1, N'$') AS UserID
WHERE [Role].[key] = UserID.[key];
```

**Output**

| ID | Role | ControlUnit | UserID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0019 | SPV | 00G (nol) | 0016506 |
| 0019 | TL | 00G (nol) | 0016551 |
| 0019 | CS | 00G (nol) | 0016541 |
| 0023 | SPV | 14I | 1458506 |
| 0023 | CS | 14I | 1458541 |
| 0023 | TL | 14I | 0435551 |
| 0019 | SPV | 0C3 | 0435506 |
| 0019 | CS | 0C3 | 0435541 |
| 0019 | TL | 0C3 | 0435551 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use STRING_SPLIT() function,
just make sure to normalize your separators-

- decide on one type and style of separator, for example comma
- either make sure in DB to always use only this separator
- or you can use REPLACE() functions in your query to fix it

Then you can use the STRING_SPLIT() function like this:

```
SELECT  T.ID                AS  ID,
        Roles.RoleName      AS  [Role],
        T.[Control Unit]    AS  [Control Unit],
        UserIds.UserId      AS  [User ID]

FROM    UsersToRoles        AS  T
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  S.ordinal       AS  RoleOrder,
            S.[value]       AS  RoleName
    FROM    STRING_SPLIT(T.[Role], ',') AS  S
)   AS  Roles
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  S.ordinal       AS  UserIdOrder,
            S.[value]       AS  UserId
    FROM    STRING_SPLIT(T.[User ID], ',')  AS  S
)   AS  UserIds
WHERE   UserIds.UserIdOrder =   Roles.RoleOrder
```